# Get All Relationship Data in AdonisJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, relationship, adonis.js

does anyone know how to retrieve all the data including from the relationship in AdonisJS ? ,
so I want to retrieve the user data from the User Model including the relationship data in the Post Model.

**get All users**

```
  public async getUsers({ response }: HttpContextContract) {
   try {
     const data = await User.all()

     return response.status(200).send({ "result": data })
   } catch(err) {
     return response.status(400).json({ error: err.message })
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need to define the relationships on your model.

A `User` has many `Posts`:

```
export default class User extends BaseModel {

  ...

  @hasMany(() => Post) //  One-to-many relationship
  public posts: HasMany<typeof Post>
}
```

A `Post` belongs to a `User`:

```
export default class Posts extends BaseModel {

  ...

  @belongsTo(() => User) //  a Post belongs to a User
  public user: BelongsTo<typeof User>
}
```

Now, in your query, you can [preload the relationship](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/models/relationships#preload-relationship).

```
const users = await User
  .query()
  .preload('posts')
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
You can use `belongsTo` in User model to make relationship data with Post model

```
post_model() {
  return this.belongsTo("App/Models/Post")
}
```

Second:
Call the model use query like this:

```
await User.query()
  .with("post_model", builder => {
    builder.select("id", "name", "post")
  })
```